# Windows 8.1 Pro won't let us set a blank password (no password)?

Tags: windows-8.1, passwords

A friend of mine has a Windows 8.1 Pro system, and she is tired of having to enter the password all the time, and just wants there to be no password on the system. But when I tried to help do that, set a blank password, it generates an error:

```
The password you entered doesn't meet password policy requirements.
Try one that's longer or more complex.
```

So I googled that, and came up with a fix involving going into secpol.msc and disabling complex password requirements under the Password policy. Problem is, it was already disabled!

In that section of the policy manager is shows minimum password length = 0 and password complexity requirements Disabled.

How can we get this machine to not have a password? So far I am stumped, have I overlooked anything obvious?

Again, we DO have the current password, and it works, BUT we want to be able to log into the machine with NO password required - we want to remove the password from the User. How?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this PC part of a work Domain?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, it's used at home as a standalone. Plugged right into the Time Warner internet.

Comment: Can you create a new administrator account with no password?

Comment: That's a good question. I will try that next time I am over there. My *guess* is no, but I will report back.

Comment: OK, went and tried making a brand new admin account on her machine, and it worked just fine. So for some reason her existing account is not letting me set a blank password but any other account seems to be fine.

Now what should I try to get the password out of her existing account? Moving her to a new account would be too much trouble.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you remove the password from the old account when logged into the new admin account?

Comment: That's what I had hoped, but no. Same issue. I'm beginning to think that account is simply bugged.

Comment: You can migrate the old user account to a new one. [See step 4 but skip first paragraph as you already have the new user account](http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/software/8070/how-to-fix-a-windows-vista-or-7-corrupt-user-profile-the-user-profile-service-failed), No need to enable hidden admin accoount either, be logged into the new account and copy data as instructed

Comment: That's quite interesting, let me check with her if she would like me to give that a whirl, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this will do it:

Autologon for Windows v3.01
technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb963905.aspx

I've been using it for a couple of years with zero issues

Jeff

Comment: Well, that would get us past the password, and we may end up doing a solution like this, which I had previously considered. But what my question really is, is how can we actually remove the password altogether? Thanks.